# iOS: Autolayout and popOverController issue (possible Xcode bug)

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, xib, popover

I am displaying my `popOverController` for iPhone and iPad in the code below.

```
 ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom ==
    UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(296, 476); //your custom size.
} else {
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(252, 436.5);
}

 vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
 vc.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
 vc.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
 vc.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(screenWidth / 2, self.view.height / 2, 1, 1);

[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

UIPopoverPresentationController *popOverController =  vc.popoverPresentationController;
popOverController.permittedArrowDirections = 0;
```

However, there seems to be a class size issue occurring. It seems that iPhone size is being used and not the iPad size at all even when running an iPad device. Eventhough in interface builder it shows two different sizes for the buttons depending on the device that is selected.

Edit: For example, I have a viewcontroller.xib that has buttons. There two different button sizes depending on the actual device. On the iPhone, the buttons have a dimension of 50 x 50. On iPad it has a dimension of 430 x 430. In interface builder, this shows up correctly. However, when running an iPad device, the buttons show as 50 x 50 when it suppose to be 430 x 430.

Comment: What do you mean by "size"? On iPhone, you won't even see a popover; you will see a fullscreen presented view controller. So how do you know what the "size" should be? Please show screen shots.

Comment: For example, I have a viewcontroller.xib that has buttons. There two different button sizes depending on the actual device. On the iPhone, the buttons have a dimension of 50 x 50. On iPad it has a dimension of 430 x 430. In interface builder, this shows up correctly. However, when running an iPad device, the buttons show as 50 x 50 when it suppose to be 430 x 430. And I do have a popover on the iPhone as well.

Comment: Okay, I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional constraints in the storyboard use *size classes*.

The horizontal size class on a popover-presented view controller on an iPad is Compact, just like on an iPhone. That is why you are seeing the iPhone size for the buttons.

To see that this is true, override `viewDidAppear:` in your ViewController class to NSLog `self.traitCollection`. You will see that the horizontal size class is Compact.

This makes sense, because a popover is like an iPhone-sized window appearing on the iPad. That, in fact, is the whole *point* of a popover.

Comment: Is there a way around have two different size buttons for iPhone and iPad without resorting to using multiple xib files (I am using xib). Also, I am going to award you with the correct answer.

Comment: Yes there is, I think. You can tell the presentation controller to lie to the popover and tell it that the trait collection has a Regular width. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipresentationcontroller/1618335-overridetraitcollection?language=objc